# WPF How to set checkbox in Gridview binding in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

style that I have to create in code-behind. It has a checkbox that looks like this..

```
     <GridView>


  <GridViewColumn Width="30">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <CheckBox/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>-->
                            <GridViewColumn  Header="Groups"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Groups}"/>
                           <GridViewColumn Header="SiteTitle" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SiteTitle}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn  Header="SiteUrl" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SiteUrl}"/>
                        </GridView>
```

How I do  in code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this style in `Resources` and give it a `x:Name`.Let's assume the given name is `CustomCheckboxTemplate` , then a sample code will look like :

```
 DynamicallyCreatedCheckbox.Style = (Style)FindResource("CustomCheckboxTemplate");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it's Working  Thank You  @zack    but it's not working in my particular Column

Comment: what do u mean by particular column ?

Comment: i want use checkbox in groups in other window if selected group

Comment: I know my code helped you so please mark it as the answer , and about the column , go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911159/datagrid-wpf-column-styling-programmatically-not-xaml) , the first answer will save your day

Comment: No .. anyone with rep can mark it as answer ... Maybe it says you can mark it as answer after 10-15 mins ?